# Split a list of dictionary of dictionaries into a single dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion, pyodbc

I'm trying to take JSON from the actions of a Trello board and put these into a MS SQL database.
My code looks at every board my user account has access to.
Each board has a list of actions
Each action in a dictionary
But some of the dictionary values are dictionaries themselves. i.e. nested dictionaries

I end up with a list of dictionaries of varying length which also could contain nested dictionaries of varying length
I am trying to simplify each action / each dictionary into a single dictionary so I can use the key as the column header for the SQL table and so I can insert the values to SQL (using pyodbc) as a single dictionary. Attempting to an insert with pyodbc with a dictionary with a nested dictionary produces a key error. No problems if all of the values are strings etc

Example a single action might be of the format below.  The keys in the dictionary vary, so if a thing didnt happen it wouldnt be in the dictionary and so the dictionary will vary in length and number of keys - and so I cant just hard code for all the keys

{'id': 'xxxxx', 'idMemberCreator': 'xxxxx', 'data': {'reason': 'xxxxx', 'board': {'id': 'xxxxx'}, 'organization': {'id': 'xxxxx', 'name': 'xxxxx'}}, 'type': 'xxxxx', 'date': 'xxxxx', 'appCreator': 'xxxxx', 'limits': {}, 'memberCreator': {'id': 'xxxxx', 'username': 'xxxxx', 'activityBlocked': 'xxxxx', 'avatarHash': 'xxxxx', 'avatarUrl': 'xxxxx', 'fullName': 'xxxxx', 'idMemberReferrer': 'xxxxx', 'initials': 'x', 'nonPublic': {}, 'nonPublicAvailable': 'xxxxx'}}

notice the dictionary contains several dictionaries e.g. 'data'

I'm trying to loop through this to break this up into a dictionary that does not contain dictionaries so it might look something like below

{'id': 'xxxxx', 'idMemberCreator': 'xxxxx', 'data reason': 'xxxxx', 'data board': {'id': 'xxxxx'}, 'data organization': {'id': 'xxxxx', 'name': 'xxxxx'}, 'type': 'xxxxx', 'date': 'xxxxx', 'appCreator': 'xxxxx', 'limits': None, ... }

as python cannot tell the data type inside a list (only if a value is in the list) I thought of creating a check function like below

```
 def checkfordict(action):
     for k,v in action.items():
         if type(v) is dict:
             return True
```

and using this in part of a loop to remove the nested dictionaries over several iterations

```
>>> for action in actions:
...     while checkfordict(action):
...         for k,v in action.items():
...             if type(v) is dict:
...                 for k2,v2 in v.items():
...                     temp[k+k2] = v2
...             else:
...                 temp[k] = v
...         temp
...         action = temp
```

but this causes the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 4, in 
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

I want this to work recursively until all the nested dictionaries have been modified and I don't think that will work using the copy function as then it will only iterate once and not keep iterating until all the nested dictionaries are gone.

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not modify the object you are iterating over.

If you feed it to the `pandas.json_normalize(...)` you can see all that it is flattened.

```
>>> pd.json_normalize(b, sep="_").columns
Index(['id', 'idMemberCreator', 'type', 'date', 'appCreator', 'data_reason',
       'data_board_id', 'data_organization_id', 'data_organization_name',
       'memberCreator_id', 'memberCreator_username',
       'memberCreator_activityBlocked', 'memberCreator_avatarHash',
       'memberCreator_avatarUrl', 'memberCreator_fullName',
       'memberCreator_idMemberReferrer', 'memberCreator_initials',
       'memberCreator_nonPublicAvailable'],
      dtype='object')
```

Also quick search pointed to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flattening-json-objects-in-python/

```
# Function for flattening 
# json
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
  
    def flatten(x, name =''):
          
        # If the Nested key-value 
        # pair is of dict type
        if type(x) is dict:
              
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
                  
        # If the Nested key-value
        # pair is of list type
        elif type(x) is list:
              
            i = 0
              
            for a in x:                
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
  
    flatten(y)
    return out
```

Which gives

```
>>> flatten_json(b)
{'id': 'xxxxx', 'idMemberCreator': 'xxxxx', 'data_reason': 'xxxxx', 'data_board_id': 'xxxxx', 'data_organization_id': 'xxxxx', 'data_organization_name': 'xxxxx', 'type': 'xxxxx', 'date': 'xxxxx', 'appCreator': 'xxxxx', 'memberCreator_id': 'xxxxx', 'memberCreator_username': 'xxxxx', 'memberCreator_activityBlocked': 'xxxxx', 'memberCreator_avatarHash': 'xxxxx', 'memberCreator_avatarUrl': 'xxxxx', 'memberCreator_fullName': 'xxxxx', 'memberCreator_idMemberReferrer': 'xxxxx', 'memberCreator_initials': 'x', 'memberCreator_nonPublicAvailable': 'xxxxx'}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is way better than I was expecting. 
With this I might not even need to use SQL and can use Jupyter notebook instead

Comment: to turn it back into a dictionary I used, 
dict(zip(list(pd.json_normalize(actions[0]).columns), pd.json_normalize(actions[0]).values[0].tolist()))